# User input recorded from multiple text boxes and put into MySQL

Tags: mysql, user-input

I'm running into a brick wall and have spent multiple hours trying to research how to do this and I'm at the point I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question.

I have a page for recording user input in multiple boxes. I've made a separate file for my text box function which feeds into the main page. I want to be able to click next and record all the use input from the text boxes into a MySQL database.

The problem I'm running into seems to be that the main page doesn't know there's user input just that there is a text box, so I can't record anything, while if I change the text input file it defeats the purpose of creating one so that I can use text boxes anywhere.

#### Main page

```
import pygame
import Test
import button
import sys
import mysql.connector

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Main Page")
icon = pygame.image.load('icons8-robber-32.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
colour_active = pygame.Color('orange')
colour_inactive = pygame.Color('Yellow')
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)

start_image = pygame.image.load('play.png').convert_alpha()
exit_image = pygame.image.load('exit.png').convert_alpha()
menu_image = pygame.image.load('menu.png').convert_alpha()
back_image = pygame.image.load('back.png').convert_alpha()
next_image = pygame.image.load('next.png').convert_alpha()


def register():
    input_box1 = Test.inputBox(210, 105, 140, 32, "First Name: ")
    input_box2 = Test.inputBox(210, 160, 140, 32)

    input_boxes = [input_box1, input_box2]

    back_button = button.Button(100, 450, back_image, 0.2)
    next_button = button.Button(450, 450, next_image, 0.2)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(screen)

        if back_button.draw(screen):
            print("no")
        if next_button.draw(screen):
            sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()

start_button = button.Button(100, 150, start_image, 0.2)
exit_button = button.Button(250, 150, exit_image, 0.2)
menu_button = button.Button(400, 150, menu_image, 0.2)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((150, 255, 100))
    if start_button.draw(screen):
        print("no")
    if exit_button.draw(screen):
        sys.exit()

    if menu_button.draw(screen):
        register()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.QUIT()
sys.exit()
```

#### Text box file

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

colour_active = pygame.Color('orange')
colour_inactive = pygame.Color('Yellow')
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)

class inputBox():

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h)
        self.color = colour_inactive
        self.text = text
        self.text_surface = font.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self,event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False

            self.color = colour_active if self.active else colour_inactive
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.text)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text [:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                self.text_surface = font.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.w = max(100, self.text_surface.get_width() + 10)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)
```

Comment: I solved this thank you, took me a long time but I was getting know returns from input_box1.self.text - turns out when I got rid of the self it works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `self.text` file in the main code. So instead of writing `input_box1.self.text`, it was just `input_box1.text`.